# Keeps printing output in the Linux terminal until it reads an input

Tags: java, linux, infinite-loop

I am a newbie in Java and Object-oriented programming. Let's say I have created a 2d array game grid and initialized the array with characters, which looks like the following:

```
+++++
+...+
+++++
```

I want to update the **...** with **123**. 
I have the following code:

```
while (true) {
    if (....) map.printMap();   //what should be the condition here??
    else ...dosomethingelse...;
}
```

My question is, does there exist a method which I can place in the ***if*** condition so that the grid will keeps printing by itself before an input 1? If it detects an input 1, it will stop printing at that moment, execute the ***else*** condition to update the grid, then print out as follows:

```
+++++
+1..+
+++++
```

After that, it continues to keep printing the updated grid on screen, and follows the same pattern above until all of the **...** are updated.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to look into something like [JCurses](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) for continuously-updated terminal window applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
try {
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(reader);
    while (true) {
        map.printMap();
        if(!reader.ready()) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            continue;
        }
        String command = buf.readLine();
        System.out.println("Command: " + command);
    }
} catch(Exception e ){ 
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use two threads for this:

- Thread 1 periodically (?) updates the screen until a flag is set.
- Thread 2 uses a blocking read on console input to get input from the user, and then sets the flag when appropriate.

You could also attempt to do this by calling the `available()` method, but the specified semantics of that method are such that it is hard (impossible?) to use it portably; i.e. without relying on behavior of the console input stack that could vary from one OS to another.

Comment: Hey Stephen, can you provide a code example for your suggestion?

Comment: Nope.  Try reading the Java tutorial stream on threads and concurrency: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/